# Suggested edits show an edit but no edit there

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

On the /review tab, I have the following

[image: Suggested edit]

But there is no suggested edit there.

> There are no pending suggested edits to review!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [it was *your* edit!](https://movies.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/161)

Can't exactly let you review *that*, right? What'd be the point!

That said, I approved it - so now you shouldn't see any indication of pending suggested edits.

Comment: Thanks, I realize that now but it's a little confusing don't you think? Why show a suggested edit you cannot act on though?

Comment: We don't. That's what confused you - the not-showing-it bit. The extension of this would be to also decrement the total number of pending edits by the number of edits suggested by the viewer, which would probably make it even less confusing (except for folks wondering why their suggested edits don't seem to show up anywhere), at the cost of additional per-user processing.

Comment: Ah okay makes sense